# xgboost prediction in R is different on sparse and dense matrices

Tags: r, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I've trained a simple model using `xgboost` library in R on a matrix produced by sparse.model.matrix, then I made a prediction on two validation datasets - one created by `sparse.model.matrix` from `Matrix` and the second one by `model.matrix` from `stats`. To my great suprise results differ significantly. Sparse and dense matrices have identical dimensions, all data is numerical and there are no missing values.

Mean prediction on these two sets is the following:

- dense validation matrix: 0.5009256
- sparse validation matrix: 0.4988821

Is it a feature or a bug?

**Update:**

I've noticed that error does not occur when all values are positive xor negative. If the variable `x1` has a definition `x1=sample(1:7, 2000, replace=T)`, mean prediction is the same in both cases.

Code in R:

```
require(Matrix)
require(xgboost)

valid <- data.frame(y=sample(0:1, 2000, replace=T), x1=sample(-1:5, 2000, replace=T), x2=runif(2000))
train <- data.frame(y=sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T), x1=sample(-1:5, 10000, replace=T), x2=runif(10000))

sparse_train_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(~ ., data=train[, c("x1", "x2")])
d_sparse_train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(sparse_train_matrix, label = train$y)

sparse_valid_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(~ ., data=valid[, c("x1", "x2")])
d_sparse_valid_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(sparse_valid_matrix, label = valid$y)

valid_matrix <- model.matrix(~ ., data=valid[, c("x1", "x2")])
d_valid_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(valid_matrix, label = valid$y)

params = list(objective = "binary:logistic", seed = 99, eval_metric = "auc")

sparse_w <- list(train=d_sparse_train_matrix, test=d_sparse_valid_matrix)
set.seed(1)
sprase_fit_xgb <- xgb.train(data=d_sparse_train_matrix, watchlist=sparse_w, params=params, nrounds=100)

p1 <- predict(sprase_fit_xgb, newdata=d_valid_matrix, type="response")
p2 <- predict(sprase_fit_xgb, newdata=d_sparse_valid_matrix, type="response")

mean(p1); mean(p2)
```

My sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250 
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C 
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250

attached base packages: [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages: [1] xgboost_0.6-4 Matrix_1.2-10 data.table_1.10.4 dplyr_0.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] Rcpp_0.12.11 lattice_0.20-35 assertthat_0.2.0 grid_3.4.1 
[5] R6_2.2.2 magrittr_1.5 stringi_1.1.5 rlang_0.1.1 
[9] bindrcpp_0.2 tools_3.4.1 glue_1.1.1 compiler_3.4.1 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.1 bindr_0.1 tibble_1.3.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1634) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/porto-seguro-safe-driver-prediction/discussion/40835) that this is expected behaviour and make sense to me.